# Changing vector with a function in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm having problems with a simple code in Rcpp. My problem is that I want to change a vector by passing it to a function. A example is:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void ones(IntegerVector x, int lx){
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < lx; i++){
       x(i) = 1;
   }
}
```

When I do in R:

```
x = rep(-1, 10)
ones(x, length(x))
```

the vector x do not change. How can i work this out?

edit:
If I pass x as &x how do I change it's values?

edit: after trying the two methods proposed in the first two answers nothing changed.

edit: restarted Rstudio and now it works....... Is it a common problem for Rstudio users?

Comment: I am not aware of rcpp, but in c++ in order pass a reference you would need to: "IntegerVector &x" instead of "IntegerVector x"

Comment: If I do it I cant access the values of x. (*x)[i], *x[i], (*x)(i) and (*x)(i) did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can do this without passing by reference since Rcpp classes are proxy objects, but you *must pass exactly the correct type of vector*. In your function signature, `x` is an `IntegerVector`, but you pass in a `NumericVector` since `rep(-1, 10)` returns a `numeric`, not an `integer`. Because of the type mismatch, the input had to be coerced to an `IntegerVector`, meaning a copy was created, and the original (`numeric` vector) was **not** modified. For example,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void ones(Rcpp::IntegerVector x, int lx) {
   for (int i = 0; i < lx; i++) {
       x[i] = 1;
   }
}

/*** R

x <- rep(-1, 10)
class(x)
#[1] "numeric"

ones(x, length(x))
x
#[1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

y <- as.integer(rep(-1, 10)) # or, rep(-1L, 10)
class(y)
#[1] "integer"

ones(y, length(y))
y
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

*/
```

---

Similarly, if `x` were typed as a `NumericVector` in your function signature, the coercion to `integer` would not be needed:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void ones_numeric(Rcpp::NumericVector x, int lx) {
   for (int i = 0; i < lx; i++) {
       x[i] = 1.0;
   }
}

/*** R

z <- rep(-1, 10)
class(z) 
#[1] "numeric"

ones_numeric(z, length(z))
z
#1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

*/
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but it still do not work :-(

Comment: I'm not really sure how that's possible. It clearly works, as demonstrated above.

Comment: @nrussell troll account?

Comment: @Coatless either that or OP is wildly incompetent...

Comment: Good answer -- the automatic cast throws in the spanner so @coatless was for once not correct: the `&` is just visual sugar as we deal with `SEXP` which are already pointers.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel proxy model woes ='(

Comment: Not to worry. We all fell into that hole. Once or twice or many times.